# Can not set environment variable on Mac OsX

Tags: java, macos, playframework, environment-variables

I have a play framework java application which uses Amazon S3 and I do not want to set my secret and access keys in the configurations, but I want to save it in environment variable to make it more secure.

I have this plugin:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import play.Application;
import play.Logger;
import play.Plugin;

public class S3Plugin extends Plugin {

    public static final String AWS_S3_BUCKET = "aws.s3.bucket";
    public static final String AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "aws.access.key";
    public static final String AWS_SECRET_KEY = "aws.secret.key";
    private final Application application;

    public static AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    public static String s3Bucket;

    @Inject
    public S3Plugin(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        String accessKey = application.configuration().getString(AWS_ACCESS_KEY);
        String secretKey = application.configuration().getString(AWS_SECRET_KEY);
        s3Bucket = application.configuration().getString(AWS_S3_BUCKET);

        if ((accessKey != null) && (secretKey != null)) {
            AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
            amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
            amazonS3.createBucket(s3Bucket);
            Logger.info("Using S3 Bucket: " + s3Bucket);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enabled() {

        System.out.println("ACCESSKEY "+ application.configuration().keys().contains(AWS_ACCESS_KEY));

        return (application.configuration().keys().contains(AWS_ACCESS_KEY) &&
                application.configuration().keys().contains(AWS_SECRET_KEY) &&
                application.configuration().keys().contains(AWS_S3_BUCKET));
    }

}
```

and method `enabled()` prints that access key is null, which means that I did not save it properly in environment variables.

I opened `.bash_profile (/Users/me/.bash_profile)` with command `atom .bash_profile` and I pasted the following:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=myAccessKey
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=mySecretKey
```

and saved it. After that, I ran `printenv` command which listed my environment variables, but neither `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` nor `AWS_SECRET_KEY` were there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is on topic here, but you are likely to get a better answer at Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to run :

```
source /Users/me/.bash_profile
```

`bash_profile` is only sourced by bash when started in interactive login mode.

Comment: I did it, now the keys are shown after I run the printenv command, but the java application is still not reading it.

Comment: It actually works. What I have to do is to run that command and after that, in the same terminal tab, use activator run, and then it reads variables properly.

Comment: @xpg94, what do you mean by activator run?